# UIScrollView with center resizable view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I am not sure if this question is duplicated but I am basically trying to get a UIScrollView that has a UIView center horizontally and vertically and its height constraint changes and I want to know how I can achieve it using only code. I would attach code but I have done plenty and I am not sure which one is correct now...

It would look like this

[image]

That's how the layout would be structured:

[image]

Caontainer view is the view that will be resized by changing the height constraint value.

- The 2 Black views are a header and a footer with constant height size.
- The view in blue will be use for appending content so the container view needs to resize height.

Here is Some code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("\(logClassName) viewDidLoad")
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.AppColors.mainViewPopupBackground

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    else{
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    let dummyView = UIView()
    dummyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(dummyView)

    dummyView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    dummyView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true


    dummyView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dummyView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dummyView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dummyView.widthAnchor,multiplier:0.85).isActive = true
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true


    contentView.addSubview(titleView)
    titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46).isActive = true

    titleView.text = title == nil ? defaultTitle:title!
    titleView.addBottomBorder(color: UIColor.AppColors.defaultSeparator, height: 1, margins: 0)


    contentView.addSubview(buttonsView)
    buttonsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46).isActive = true

    let multiplier:CGFloat = buttonDisplay == .both ? 0.5 : 1
    let constant:CGFloat = buttonDisplay == .both ? -0.5 : 0

    if buttonDisplay == .both || buttonDisplay == .cancelOnly {

        buttonsView.addSubview(cancelButton)
        cancelButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cancelButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        cancelButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cancelButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.widthAnchor, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant).isActive = true
        cancelButton.setTitle(AppHelper.printLocalized(withKey: "com.message.cancel", targetSpecific: false), for: .normal)

    }

    if buttonDisplay == .both || buttonDisplay == .confirmOnly {

        buttonsView.addSubview(confirmButton)
        confirmButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        confirmButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        confirmButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        confirmButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.widthAnchor, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant).isActive = true
        confirmButton.setTitle(AppHelper.printLocalized(withKey: "com.message.ok", targetSpecific: false), for: .normal)

    }

    buttonsView.addTopBorder(color: UIColor.AppColors.defaultSeparator, height: 1, margins: 0)


    contentView.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonsView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    //containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: defaultContentViewHeight).isActive = true


    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero


}
```

And the variables used for the code above:

```
override var title: String?{
    didSet{
        titleView.text = title!
    }
}

var buttonDisplay:ButtonDisplay = ButtonDisplay.both

lazy var scrollView:UIScrollView = {
    let aScrollView = UIScrollView()

    aScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    aScrollView.bounces = true
    aScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

    return aScrollView
}()

var defaultContentViewHeight:CGFloat{
    var constant:CGFloat!

    switch AppHelper.traitStatus{
    case .wreghreg:
        constant = 650
    case .wcomhreg:
        constant = 1600
    case .wreghcom:
        constant = 350
    case .wcomhcom:
        constant = 1300
    }

    return constant
}
lazy var contentView:MainView = {

    var rtView = MainView()

    rtView.backgroundColor = UIColor.AppColors.viewPopupBackground
    rtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return rtView

}()

lazy var titleView:MainLabel = {

    var rtLabel = MainLabel(withConfiguration: .popupTitle)
    rtLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    rtLabel.backgroundColor = .green
    return rtLabel

}()

lazy var buttonsView:UIView = {

    var rtView = UIView()
    rtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return rtView

}()
lazy var cancelButton:MainButton = {

    var rtView = MainButton(withConfiguration: .popupSecondary)

    rtView.cornerRadius = 0
    rtView.borderWidth = 0

    rtView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    rtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return rtView

}()
lazy var confirmButton:MainButton = {

    var rtView = MainButton(withConfiguration: .popup)

    rtView.cornerRadius = 0
    rtView.borderWidth = 0

    rtView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(confirmAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    rtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return rtView

}()

/*** USE THIS VIEW FOR APPENDING THE SPECIFIC CONTENT ***/
lazy var containerView:MainView = {

    var rtView = MainView()

    rtView.borderWidth = 0
    rtView.cornerRadius = 0

    rtView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    rtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return rtView

}()
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear from your question how your view (and even which view should be resized) please be more clear.

Comment: sorry @inokey . Is it better now?

Comment: I don't know the logic you're trying to achieve but it seems like you're creating something that it is known as `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

Comment: It is not... I have added some code. I want to have UIView inside a UIScrollView that resizes it height and it is center in the middle

Comment: Well, it doesn't make much sense but you need to set your header view top constraint to be greater than or equal to superview, your footer constraint to be less than or equal to superview and your content view top and bottom should be attached by equal relation to the header and footer respectively. In any case building the system you are building will most likely present a lot of problems in case you'd like to a add stack view or unknown length string in it. I'm pretty sure that the original request for this feature could be solved in a more elegant way.

Comment: Try this one [gist](https://gist.github.com/elmodos/97ce873009b745b7734bd3e28920b585)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

Set width and height constraints of the "root" view in your scrollView equal to the scrollView, but set the priority on the Height constraint to 250.

Then put your header, "expanding content" and footer views in a stackView. Center the stackView vertically in the "root" view, and set its Top and Bottom constraints to `>= 8` (to leave 8-pts padding).

Now, as your "expanding content" view changes height (based on its content), the stackView will get taller, but remain vertically centered.

When you've added enough content to exceed the height of the scrollView, the low Priority on the "root" view will allow it to grow in height, and become scrollable.

Here's the layout in storyboard:

[image]

Here's how it looks with a small amount of content:

[image]

and, when it has more content (scrolled to the bottom):

[image]

Here is the debug view:

[image]

- Light Green is the scrollView
- Dark Green is the "root" view
- Slightly darker green is the stackView
- Black Header / Footer views
- Blue "expanding content" view

Once the constraints are set correctly, no code is needed to handle adjusting the sizes or scrolling - its all handled by Auto-Layout.

To see it in action, use this code for the view controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/9/18.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var expandingLabel: UILabel!

    var nLines = 1

    @IBAction func addLineTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        nLines += 1
        setLabelText()
    }

    @IBAction func removeLineTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if nLines > 2 {
            nLines -= 1
            setLabelText()
        }
    }

    func setLabelText() -> Void {
        var s = ""
        if nLines == 0 {
            s = "Expanding Label"
        } else {
            s = (1...nLines).map({ "Line \($0)" }).joined(separator: "\n")
        }
        expandingLabel.text = s
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setLabelText()

    }

}
```

Tapping "Add a Line" and "Remove a Line" buttons do what it sounds like :)

Here's the source of the storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="DrawOn" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Vuw-Sq-3ds">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="80" width="359" height="579"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Fl6-G4-xCj" userLabel="Content View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="359" height="579"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="equalSpacing" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jvv-bQ-6hQ">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="220" width="279" height="140.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bGL-74-7Fk" userLabel="Header View">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="279" height="40"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Header View 40-pts Height" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nt9-AP-bCN" userLabel="Header Label">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="34.5" y="10" width="210" height="20.5"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.99999600649999998" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="nt9-AP-bCN" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="bGL-74-7Fk" secondAttribute="centerY" id="Ope-LL-yOC"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="nt9-AP-bCN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="bGL-74-7Fk" secondAttribute="centerX" id="ZBt-dj-US2"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="qul-fE-qXK"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </view>
                                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="HAK-GL-d2e" userLabel="Expanding Label Containing View">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="40" width="279" height="60.5"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Expanding Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ctw-D5-rv5" userLabel="Expanding Label">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="263" height="44.5"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ctw-D5-rv5" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="1sy-pt-g7z"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ctw-D5-rv5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="HAK-GL-d2e" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="NYL-G7-rQx"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="ctw-D5-rv5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="YK8-wy-8Pa"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ctw-D5-rv5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="HAK-GL-d2e" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="qfr-5Z-1gw"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </view>
                                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="O4w-A4-H6n" userLabel="Footer View">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="100.5" width="279" height="40"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Footer View 40-pts Height" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="q6s-5S-Sx9" userLabel="Footer Label">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="38" y="10" width="203.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.99999600649999998" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="q6s-5S-Sx9" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="O4w-A4-H6n" secondAttribute="centerY" id="35l-M2-X4u"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="q6s-5S-Sx9" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="O4w-A4-H6n" secondAttribute="centerX" id="TqO-pv-FLb"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="40" id="x7P-kS-KhJ"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </view>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.56031829119999998" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="jvv-bQ-6hQ" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" secondAttribute="centerY" id="bDX-eg-0dD"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="jvv-bQ-6hQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="c8T-Oc-P0W"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="jvv-bQ-6hQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="gHz-UY-a8e"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="jvv-bQ-6hQ" firstAttribute="top" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="tDD-Zr-Jne"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="jvv-bQ-6hQ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="tke-Qx-y9t"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="width" id="1LN-nS-m1O"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Rgx-xv-bed"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" secondAttribute="bottom" id="hL3-ST-FnS"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="top" id="qgo-Qw-qCM"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="height" priority="250" id="tiq-6l-uQh"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Fl6-G4-xCj" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="leading" id="yYB-d7-S2y"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="40" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NNa-E5-guI">
                                <rect key="frame" x="37.5" y="32" width="300" height="30"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jeW-uV-cnV">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="130" height="30"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Add a Line"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="addLineTapped:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="NGU-XZ-sUi"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1SN-WP-tr5">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="170" y="0.0" width="130" height="30"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <state key="normal" title="Remove a Line"/>
                                        <connections>
                                            <action selector="removeLineTapped:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="80A-rI-a0B"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </button>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="300" id="xdn-ra-Mpq"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="0as-vV-CWL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NNa-E5-guI" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="EEn-yg-Ba2"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="i1E-50-PXU"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="kep-Qo-OTQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NNa-E5-guI" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="l5O-iv-7h9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Vuw-Sq-3ds" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="60" id="pYU-HL-mIH"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="expandingLabel" destination="ctw-D5-rv5" id="oDW-fm-PtZ"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you very much for your explanation! I am really greatfull !

Comment: Hi @DonMag, I have just tested your code in the office and your approach works really well. I have just set made some adjustments by setting up a height constraint to the inner view (Blue) because I needed it like that! yo made my day! Thank you agin

Answer (score 0):

The info seems a little insufficient, though this might help:

- in the interface builder, add a constraint to your container view for height, say height = 100.
- then from the inspector, change the '=' to height '>=' 100
- now, when ever you append any content to the view in blue, it would automatically resize.

**NOTE: also set a constraint for the view in blue to be '>=' some value.**

Answer (score 0):

Based on DonMag answer, which I still feel is the best answer, I have been able to replace the UIStackView for a UIView (wrapperView) so I can add a border and I have added an innerView (green) where I can add content and I can manually choose wrapperView's view Height.

[image]

[image]
[image]